# toggle active on nav-tabs

Tags: javascript

```
$('.active').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

I know this is totally wrong but I'm new and trying to learn; What I'm trying to do is toggle the active class for the `<li>` `onclick()` really appreciate any help. Thankyou.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li role="presentation" onclick="toggleClass();">Hi</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you using? This looks like bootstrap, right?

Comment: that is correct @Drala

Comment: What is `.active`?

Comment: `.active` basically highlights/selects the `<li>` tab. so I need the onclick to toggle the `.active` class on the `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function `toggleClass`

**JS**

Create a new function toggleClass which will accept the current clicked element

```
function toggleClass(elem) {
  $(elem).toggleClass('active');
};
```

**HTML**

add `toggleClass` function to `onclick` handler & pass the current element as an argument

```
  <li role="presentation" onclick="toggleClass(this);">Hi</li>
```

**CSS**

Create a class `.active`

```
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/20hms6yp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set all other elements's classes to inactive,

```
$('.active').className = 'inactive';
$(this).className = 'active';
```

That top expression will affect all elements with the class and the bottom one will change the current clicked element.

Comment: whats inactive? OP does not ask for switching classes, he wants to toggle `active` class only.

Answer (score 0):

try  this:

```
$("nav li").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

if only for `<li>` elements with `active` class

```
$("nav li.active").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Bootstrap is supposed to work. If you are using bootstrap, use their tab js component. more on it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Basically you add a listener on those LI tags like this: (from the docs)

```
$('.nav.nav-tabs li').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

The way you did, you were toggling the state twice so in the end it would stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `$('.active').click(function())`, you should target `li` click as

```
$( "li" ).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/142/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for description about **how to use .toggleClass**.

*toggleClass: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.*

## DEMO:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
ul li{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  }
.active {
  background: #69a;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li> Link A</li>
  <li>Link B</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: thankyou this link was very useful, and will be using this in the future.